# Error Java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException -> Plugin.Fingerprint.Android.Samsung.dll

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, visual-studio-2022

I am currently upgrading **SDK to 33** as per new Google Play Store requirement.

While building Xamarin App, I am facing below error. Any idea:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Warning in C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3D62.tmp:
Unsupported usage of main-dex list. The usage of main-dex-list content for the compilation of non-DEX inputs is deprecated. See issue https://issuetracker.google.com/181858113 for context.
Error in obj\Debug\120\lp\23\jl\__reference__pass-v1.2.0.jar:com/samsung/android/sdk/pass/SpassFingerprint$b.class:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
Compilation failed with an internal error.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\120\lp\23\jl\__reference__pass-v1.2.0.jar
com/samsung/android/sdk/pass/SpassFingerprint$b.class
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:98)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.main(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:4)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\120\lp\23\jl\__reference__pass-v1.2.0.jar:com/samsung/android/sdk/pass/SpassFingerprint$b.class
    at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_3.3.75.java:0)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:75)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.b(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1133)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:2212)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:85)
    ... 1 more
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Pa.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:3960)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Pa.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1859)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Pa.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1009)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Pa.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.z2.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:33)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.z2.A0(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:101)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:102)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:100)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.z2.W(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:3)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.iI.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:191)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.t.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:16352)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.I.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.t.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:16188)
    at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.t.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:7506)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:2150)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:1028)
    at com.android.tools.r8.R8.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:2211)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:24)
    ... 4 more
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
        at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Hj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:6)
        at com.android.tools.r8.internal.Fj.a(R8_3.3.75_b7a6ff6b13548611571508fe72282c9167faa649161ca0013edfc92e19bd7e58:104)
        ... 15 more
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
 Index 4 out of bounds for length 4]
Directory 'obj\Debug\120\lp\23' is from 'Plugin.Fingerprint.Android.Samsung.dll'.   LoanServicingApp.Droid
```

I have tried upgrading the Plugin.Fingerprint.Android.Samsung to latest as well but problem still exists